# Question about Group_by in django

Tags: model, sql-order-by, annotate, django-1.3

**UPDATE** This has been confirmed to be a bug of the release 1.3. Here is the ticket http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15709

So I want to implement this SQL:

```
selelct id, count(*), max(insert_date) as m_d
from Book
group by id
```

Here is the Django ORM query:

```
 q = Book.objects.values('id').annotate(c = Count('id'), m_d = Max('insert_date')).order_by()
```

However, the translated sql is like this:

```
selelct id, count(*), max(insert_date) as m_d
from Book
group by id, id  <-here is another id! It messed up things!
```

Can any one shed some light on this? I am using Django 1.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be a bug of the release 1.3. Here is the ticket http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15709